# Query Cassandra table for every Kafka Message

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to query a cassandra table for every single kafka message.

Below is the code that I have been working on:

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
 val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
  .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
  .getOrCreate()

val topicsSet = List("Test").toSet
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
          "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
          "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
          "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
          "group.id" -> "12345",
          "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
          "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
          )
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
  ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams))

val lines = messages.map(_.value)

val lines_myobjects = lines.map(line =>
  new Gson().fromJson(line, classOf[myClass]) // The myClass is a simple case class which extends serializable
//This changes every single message into an object
)
```

Now things get complicated, I cannot get around the point where I can query the cassandra table with relevant to the message from the kafka message. Every single kafka message object has a return method.

I have tried multiple ways to get around this. For instance:

```
val transformed_data = lines_myobjects.map(myobject => {
   val forest = spark.read
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(Map( "table" -> "mytable", "keyspace" -> "mydb"))
    .load()
    .filter("userid='" + myobject.getuserId + "'")
)}
```

I have also tried `ssc.cassandraTable` which gave me no luck.

The main goal is to get all the rows from the database where the userid matches with the userid that comes from the kafka message.

One thing I would like to mention is that even though loading or querying the cassandra database every time is not efficient, the cassandra database changes everytime.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do `spark.read` or `ssc.cassandraTable` inside `.map(`. Because it means you would try to create new RDD per each message. It shouldn't work like that.

Please, sider the following options:

1 - If you could ask required data by one/two CQL queries, try to use [CassandraConnector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#connecting-manually-to-cassandra) inside the `.mapPartitions(`. Something like this:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._

val connector = ...instantiate CassandraConnector onece here
val transformed_data = lines_myobjects.mapPartitions(it => {
   connector.withSessionDo { session =>
       it.map(myobject => session.execute("CQL QUERY TO GET YOUR DATA HERE", myobject.getuserId)
})
```

2 - Otherwise (if you select by primary/partition key) consider `.joinWithCassandraTable`. Something like this:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

val mytableRDD = sc.cassandraTable("mydb", "mytable")
val transformed_data = lines_myobjects
    .map(myobject => {
       Tuple1(myobject.getuserId) // you need to wrap ids to a tuple to do join with Cassandra
    })
    .joinWithCassandraTable("mydb", "mytable")
    // process results here
```

Comment: Thank you. The second case is definitely not my option. I am wondering if the session thing is a performance killer. The query can have MB's of data. Is the work distributed across the worker nodes?

Comment: You could create session per partition. Just use .mapPartitions instead

Comment: I could not get around mapPartitions method. I am either getting that myobject.getUserId is not a member of iterator and it is expecting the iterator.

Comment: in case of `mapPartitions` you'll have an iterator of `myobject`s.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this a different way. 
The data that is flowing into Cassandra, route it through Kafka (and from Kafka send to the Cassandra with the [Kafka Connect sink](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-cassandra)). 
With your data in Kafka, you can then join between your streams of data, whether in Spark, or with Kafka's Streams API, or KSQL. 
Both Kafka Streams and KSQL support stream-table joins that you're doing here. You can see it in action with KSQL [here](http://videos.confluent.io/watch/m1LpiDwQo4Vvd4YHWKcszs) and [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-real-time-streaming-etl-from-oracle-transactional-data).